# Field type "date" is not in the list of available field types

Tags: entities, 7

I'm trying to create a new content type with a field that would contain a date. However, the drop-down list for field type doesn't have "date". What's wrong?

p.s. drupal 7.17

Comment: Have you enabled/installed date module?

Comment: I don't have 'Date' in my list of modules. Shouldn't it be in the core or I have to install it manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install the date module:

http://drupal.org/project/date

Then enable the date module and that will give you the option to add a date field to your content type. Depending on your case you might want to check also the popup calendar module that is part of the date module to ease the date input.

Comment: I'm trying to install that module, however, I receive error regarding the FTP server connection failure. As far as I understand the site needs the FTP server running to upload the module. I checked the FTP and it is running. Updating from the local file still shows the FTP error.

Comment: Are you using an FTP client to upload the files or the admin UI in the modules section to install the module?

Comment: I'm using the admin UI, section "Modules".